# Why does the system become laggy when connected to Internet?

Tags: 12.04, internet, intel, cpu, toshiba-satellite

Why when I connect my netbook to the Internet via LAN or Wifi does whole system becomes laggy? Even when in idle, the CPU monitor shows 100% usage when connected. I've had this problem about half a year now, since I installed Ubuntu 11.10.

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Toshiba NB-105 Satellite netbook with 1 GB RAM and a 1 GHz Intel Atom processor.

Here's my `syslog`:

```
$ tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog
May 23 02:45:28 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17552.933099] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:45:28 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17552.935345] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:45:28 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17552.935360] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:46:20 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17604.643371] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:46:20 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17604.649520] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:46:20 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17604.649547] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:47:11 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17656.349121] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:47:11 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17656.351373] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:47:11 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17656.351392] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:48:03 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17708.069032] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:48:03 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17708.071240] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:48:03 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17708.071254] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:48:55 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17759.901056] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:48:55 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17759.903757] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:48:55 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17759.903774] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:49:48 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17812.913124] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:49:48 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17812.915338] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:49:48 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17812.915365] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:50:40 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17864.205232] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:50:40 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17864.207449] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:50:40 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17864.207461] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:51:34 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17918.353070] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:51:34 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17918.355337] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:51:34 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17918.355347] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:52:25 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17969.913237] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:52:25 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17969.915480] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:52:25 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [17969.915506] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
May 23 02:53:17 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [18021.721949] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
May 23 02:53:17 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [18021.724196] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
May 23 02:53:17 jesselan-NB-105 kernel: [18021.724210] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Following [agc93](https://askubuntu.com/users/53518/agc93)'s suggestion to check what running processes are the most CPU-intensive, it looks like it is the gwibber.service followed by Google Chrome and Ubuntu One. What should I do about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved...

Gwibber was the one eating my resources... I had to uncheck on settings: "Start when log in"